# Does being good at Advanced Neurosurgery actually help me?

Tags: monster-loves-you

I've noticed that the odd story choice gives me points in Advanced Neurosurgery. Is that anything actually useful to me as a monster, or is that just a fake stat?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the question, so not an answer.  Advanced Neurosurgery is good for working toward a particular ending, however I don't know if having the stat actually impacts decsion-making and story choice outcomes.